# Fast application of InterpolatingFunction over transformed coordinates

Tags: performance-tuning

I have an `InterpolatingFunction` that takes $(x, y)$ coordinates as input and I would like to apply it to a series of data that is rotated by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ into $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)))$ coordinates.

Here's a sample function:

```
FunctionInterpolation[
 Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ], 
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
 {ϕ, 0, π}
 ]
```

Furthermore, if the value is off the interpolation grid I don't want to extrapolate, but would rather provide a default value. In general my use case has very steep walls and so I basically make this infinity.

Now, I've written code to do this quickly using `Compile`, but I'd like to generalize this and potentially do better. The `Compile` code is long (and still has a `"MainEvaluate"` call) so I'll post it as an answer at some later time.

So what's the *fastest* way to apply that `InterpolatingFunction` to a transformed set of coordinates (we can assume the transformation can be compiled) with a default value off the standard grid?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up the function and the default value. Notice that I force Mathematica to use machine precision numbers in `f`.

```
f = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ], {θ, 0., 2. π}, {ϕ, 0., 1. π}];
default = 0.;
```

Generating several example points.

```
n = 100000;
x = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {n}];
y = RandomReal[{0, Pi}, {n}];
{x, y} = 1/Sqrt[2.] {x + y, x - y};
```

Now, let's find the points within the domain of `f`:

```
inregionQ = UnitStep[x] UnitStep[2 Pi - x] UnitStep[y] UnitStep[Pi - y];
idx = Random`Private`PositionsOf[inregionQ, 1];
```

And let's apply `f` only to these points:

```
result = ConstantArray[default, Length[x]];
result[[idx]] = f[x[[idx]], y[[idx]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.741009

It is still not super fast but the reason is that `InterpolatingFunction`s are rather slow. As we may use a regular tensor grid for `f`, applying it to many points at once could be way faster with a more appropriate binning and parallelization strategy...

Just for comparison: This is the timing of the evalation of the *original* function:

```
result2 = ConstantArray[default, Length[x]];
result2[[idx]] = Sin[x[[idx]]] Cos[y[[idx]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.001445

It is more than 500 times faster. This tells us (i) that the function to interpolate has to be *very* complex in order to take advantage of `FunctionInterpolation` and (ii) that there must be *a lot* potential to improve  the performance of `InterpolationFunction`.

Comment: Interesting approach. Never seen ``Random`Private`PositionsOf`` but it looks useful, esp. with `UnitStep` for picking indices.

Comment: Yeah, Carl Woll used it a couple of times. I _really_ like it. It is much faster than `Position` for finding integers and it is also faster than `Pick[Range[Length[inregionQ]],inregionQ,1]`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah. Dunno. It is a black box for me and I only use it for integer lists anyway. I suspect a compiled function behind it, so I do not expect much flexibility from it.

Comment: Per your comparison, I have no analytic form for my original thing and probably no hope ever to have an analytic form. I could try some fits but what fit to use it a mystery as it's a high dimensional system. Hence my hope to deal with interpolation really nicely.

Comment: Yeah. I did not mean to poke you about that. My hope was more towards a random WRI developer stumbling upon this and feeling an itching... ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following produces an [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) that does the desired extrapolation.  It's about the same speed as @Henrik's, but I think it's convenient.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Interpolation},
 Unprotect[Interpolation];
 Interpolation[args___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   With[{default = 0.},
    Interpolation[args, "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {default &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
    ]];
 Protect[Interpolation];
 ifn = FunctionInterpolation[
   Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0., 2. \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0., N@\[Pi]}]
 ]
```

Henrik's example with `SeedRandom[1]` (`Length@idx` --> `65673`), followed by the `ifn` above on Henrik's input and the full x,y input:

```
result[[idx]] = f[x[[idx]], y[[idx]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.801  *)

result[[idx]] = ifn[x[[idx]], y[[idx]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.753  *)

result[[idx]] = ifn[x, y]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.814  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version of this. I use it internally in a discretized function object to provide a nice compiled functional form. One other thing this does is allow you to set some coordinates to a constant value to take slices through the function:

```
iInterpCompile[interp_, coords_, preProcessor_, def_, min_] :=

 Module[{potInterp = interp, dom = interp[[1]], j = 1},
  Block[{crds, pt, gps},
   Module[
    {
     getPot,
     varBlock,
     varBlock2,
     preCoords
     },
    getPot[a_] := Apply[potInterp, a];
    preCoords =
     Quiet@
      preProcessor@
       Map[
        If[# === Automatic, 
          Compile`GetElement[crds, j++], 
          #
          ] &,
        coords
        ];
    j = 1;
    (* bounds checking for test *)
    With[
     {
      test =
       With[
        {
         tests =
          MapThread[
           #[[1]] <=
             If[NumericQ[#2], 
              j++; #2, 
              Compile`GetElement[pt, j++]
              ] <= #[[2]] &, 
           {dom, preCoords}
           ]
         },
        If[MemberQ[tests, False],
         False,
         And @@ DeleteCases[tests, True]
         ]
        ],
      crdSpec = preCoords,
      means = Mean /@ dom,
      fn =
       Compile[
        {{crds, _Real, 1}},
        Evaluate@preCoords,
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
        ]
      },
     Compile @@

      Hold[(* True Compile body but with Hold for code injection *)
     {{gps, _Real, 2}},
       Module[
        {
         pts = fn@gps,
         ongrid = Table[0, {i, Length@gps}],
         intres,
         midpt = means,
         interpvals,
         interpcounter,
         interppts,
         i = 1,
         barrier = def,
         minimum = min
         },
        interppts = Table[midpt, {i, Length@pts}];
        (* Find points in domain *)
        interpcounter = 0;
        Do[
         If[test,
          ongrid[[i]] = 1;
          interppts[[++interpcounter]] = pt
          ];
         i++,
         {pt, pts}
         ];
        (* Apply InterpolatingFunction only once (one MainEval call) *)

                If[interpcounter > 0,
         intres = interppts[[;; interpcounter]];
         interpvals = getPot[Transpose@intres] - minimum;
         (* Pick points that are in domain *)

         interpcounter = 0;
         Map[
          If[# == 1, interpvals[[++interpcounter]], barrier] &,
          ongrid
          ],
         Table[barrier, {i, Length@gps}]
         ]
        ],
       {{getPot[_], _Real, 1}},
       RuntimeOptions -> {
         "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False,
         "WarningMessages" -> False
         },
       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
       ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]

Options[InterpCompile] =
  {
   "CoordinateTransformation" -> Identity,
   "Minimum" -> 0.,
   "Default" -> 0.,
   "Mode" -> "Vector"
   };
InterpCompile[
  interp_, 
  coordSpec : {(Automatic | _?NumericQ) ..} | Automatic : Automatic,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 If[OptionValue["Mode"] === "Vector",
  iInterpCompile[
   interp,
   Replace[
    coordSpec, 
    Automatic :> ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@interp[[1]]]
    ],
   OptionValue["CoordinateTransformation"],
   OptionValue["Default"],
   OptionValue["Minimum"]
   ]
  ]
```

Here's a sample usage. First set up the compiled function:

```
ga =
  CoordinateBoundsArray[
   {{0., 2. π}, {0., 1. π}},
   {π/24., π/24.}
   ];
fn =
  Interpolation@
   Flatten[
    Join[
     ga,
     Map[
      {Sin[#[[1]]]*Cos[#[[2]]]} &,
      ga,
      {2}
      ],
     3
     ],
    1
    ];
cf =
  InterpCompile[fn,
   "CoordinateTransformation" ->
    (1/Sqrt[2.]*
       {
        #[[2]] + #[[1]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]
        }
      &
     )];
```

Then test the timing:

```
cf@testGrid; // RepeatedTiming

{0.47, Null}
```

And plot the result:

```
cf@testGrid // ListPlot3D[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image]

It's only barely faster than Henrik's method and multiple orders of magnitude more complex, but on the other hand it's pretty much fully general, which is convenient.

We can also use it to take slices through the interpolation:

```
With[
     {
      cf2 =
       InterpCompile[fn,
        {Automatic, #},
        "CoordinateTransformation" ->
         (1/Sqrt[2.]*
            {
             #[[2]] + #[[1]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]
             }
           &
          )]
      },
     Transpose@{#, cf2@Transpose@{#}} &@Range[-8, 8, .001] // 
      ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 250] &
     ] & /@ Range[-3, 3] // Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]